# Check if expression in directive is defined?

Tags: angularjs

In my directive I use expression:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        func: "&?"
    },
    controller: 'directiveCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
}

function directiveCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.isFunc = angular.isDefined(vm.func) || false;
}
```

How to check if `func` is defined? Now it's always defined:/

```
<my-directive></my-directive>

<my-directive func='myFunc()'></my-directive>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the link function of the directive as below:

```
 return{
     restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            func: "&?"
        },
        controller: 'directiveCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){
         if(attrs.func) {
         attrs.$observe('func', function(value) {
         console.log(value);
       });
      }
    }
```

Comment: That works - thanks I'm using `link: function (scope, element, attrs) {if (attrs.func) {scope.vm.isFunc=true;}}`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
function directiveCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.isFunc = angular.isDefined($scope.func) || false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the parentheses were a mistake. But my solution works with a controller